# Solr Replication Starts periodically

Tags: solr

Under what conditions does solr starts replicating from the start, we have noticed that in our master slave setup solr periodically start replicating the entire index from the beginning.

We have not made any changes to schema or config files, in-spite of that full replication get's triggered. How can this be avoided.

Regards,
Ayush

Comment: how are the replication settings in your configuration ? are they configured for periodic poll ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435652/solr-replication-keeps-downloading-entire-index-from-master